# Change Html and toggleClass

Tags: jquery

I am triyng to build a foote that I can close clicking on a button (Arrow icon font)...
I would like to change the arrow when the footer is open and come back to the original html when is closed....

This is the website [Claremont](http://dev.claremonthoteldouglas.co.uk/)

and this is the JQuery code that I am triyng to create

```
    $('.footer').addClass('closed');

    $('.footer').on('click', '.more-less', function() {
        $('.footer').toggleClass('closed open');
    });

    if ( $('.footer.open') === true) { 
        $('.more-less').html('<i class="icon-arrow_down"></i>');    
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: You said you want to "come back to the original html when is closed" - what does that original HTML look like?

Comment: Hi The Original is Arrow up <i class="icon-arrow_up"></i>

Comment: Include 2 arrows and display the chosen based on the parent's class, and you are done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you might be looking for is to test the condition after clicking the link and change the icon based on the state(open/close)

To test whether an element has a class use [.hasClass()](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/)

Your condition `$('.footer.open')` returns a jQuery wrapper element, so your condition will never be true

```
var $footer = $('.footer').addClass('closed');

$footer.on('click', '.more-less', function () {
    $footer.toggleClass('closed open');
    if ($footer.hasClass('open')) {
        $(this).html('<i class="icon-arrow_down"></i>');
    } else {
        $(this).html('<i class="icon-arrow_up"></i>');
    }
});
```

Comment: Solved! Works Perfecly

Answer (score 0):

```
    $('.footer').addClass('closed');

    $('.footer').on('click', '.more-less', function() {
           $('.footer').toggleClass('closed open');

       if ( $('.footer').hasClass('open') { 
           $('.more-less').html('<i class="icon-arrow_down"></i>');    
       }
       else
       {
           $('.more-less').html('<i class="icon-arrow_up"></i>');  
       }

   });
```

Answer (score 0):

Or even cheaper:

```
$('.footer').on('click', '.more-less', function() {
    $('.footer').toggleClass('closed open');
    $(this).find('i').toggleClass('icon-arrow_down icon-arrow_up');
});
```